# Computed column from other table as Primary Key SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I've found several related post, but none has answered my question. Is it possible on SQL Server to make a Primary Key from a computed column from another table?

I have this function which will get the datetime from my theader table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetTransactionDate(@tranid nchar(18))
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dtstamp DATETIME
    SELECT @dtstamp = dtstamp FROM theader 
        WHERE transactionid = @tranid ORDER BY dtstamp ASC
    RETURN @dtstamp
END
GO
```

And I'm trying to alter my existing tdetail table to add the new PK dtstamp

```
-- Drop existing constraints
ALTER TABLE tdetail
    DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_tdetail]

-- Add new column
ALTER TABLE tdetail
    ADD dtstamp AS GetTransactionDate(transactionid)

-- Re-create constraints with dtstamp
ALTER TABLE tdetail
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_tdetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(transactionid, offerid, divisionid, dtstamp)
```

Our transactionid are just valid for 1 year (`dayOfYear + "." + generatedSequence`), and we're planning to extend its retention for several more years thats why we're trying to make the dtstamp a primary key.

```
**theader table**
transactionid                 dtstamp
269.A0000009           2017-09-26 20:00:00.000
269.A0000009           2018-09-26 20:25:21.973

**tdetail table**
269.A0000009  
269.A0000009    (ERROR – duplicate PK)
```

If using computed columns are not possible, what might be a better approach?

**UPDATE**

I have thought a better approach which is: adding a nullable column with default `YEAR(GETDATE())` value -> updating the tables from `null` dtstamp to the value of the theader -> finally altering the dtstamp column to `not null` and making it a primary key. Is this okay? I'll just make the tdetails.dtstamp a `smallint` and when I join theader and tdetails - i'll just make the `where` clause equals to `YEAR(theader.dtstamp)`. Thoughts?

Comment: Why does it have to be the `dtstamp` from the other table? Would not having your own `dtstamp` column populated on insert allow you to work out how the rows from these two tables correspond with each other?

Answer (score 1):

For create constraint on computed column it must be declared as persisted, which you can't do, if you have computed column defined as non-deterministic. Your function is not deterministic, so you can not use it as constraint.

In my opinion, the best way is insert/update trigger on theader table, which will update relevant rows in table tdetail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add it to PK:

> A computed column can be used as a key column in an index or as part of any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint, if the computed column value is defined by a **deterministic** expression and the data type of the result is allowed in index columns. 
>   - [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

If You reference any table in a user-defined function then it is non-deterministic.

> If using computed columns are not possible, what might be a better approach?

Don't add it to PK. As I understood, transactionid uniquely identifies it's date, so adding it to PK/Clustered Key makes no sense, even worse, it can bring an additional overhead - remember that clustered key is part of any non-clustered index:

> If the table has a clustered index, or the index is on an indexed view, the row locator is the clustered index key for the row. - [Nonclustered Index Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide?view=sql-server-2017#nonclustered-index-architecture)

Comment: No, transactionid only identifies the dayInYears. Example: January 1 is day '1' and December 31 is '365'. On the next year, it's possible to have duplicate transactionid. Please see example at the bottom of the post.

Comment: But GetTransactionDate function returns always the lastest date... There is no way to have two dates for the same transaction. So in tdetail table there is a relation transactionId-lastest date.

Comment: Yeah you're actually right. I didn't noticed that. Thanks! I have thought a better approach which is: adding a nullable column with default `YEAR(GETDATE())` value -> updating the tables from `null` dtstamp to the value of the theader -> finally altering the dtstamp column to `not null` and making it a primary key. Is this okay? I'll just make the tdetails.dtstamp a `smallint` and when I join theader and tdetails - i'll just make the `where` clause equals to `YEAR(theader.dtstamp)`. Thoughts?